# only final output is being displayed

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a program to roll three random dice with n number of sides (determined by user input), and then continue rolling the dice and showing the random numbers until all three numbers are the same.

I think my logic is fine, but the page only shows the final row where all the numbers are the same and not the ones prior to it (where they are not all the same).

```
{
  let sidesNumber = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number of sides for your dice:", ""));

   let output1 = -1;
   let output2 = -2;
   let output3 = -3;

   while( output1 != output2 || output1 != output3 )
   {
       output1 = Math.floor((Math.random()* sidesNumber + 1));
       output2 = Math.floor((Math.random()* sidesNumber + 1));
       output3 = Math.floor((Math.random()* sidesNumber + 1));
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output1 + " " + output2 + " " + output3;
   }
}
```

Comment: every time your loop runs you reset the inner html, overriding whatever it contained before. You may have to print your output to a list item within a list instead

Comment: Did you mean `output1 += ...`? The reason they are all the same is because they always get redefined as `Math.floor((Math.random()* sidesNumber + 1))`, so they all get the same output

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is you are not appending `output1`, `output2`, and `output3` the `Math.floor((Math.random()* sidesNumber + 1))`, you are redefining the whole variable.

For example,

```js
   let output1 = -1;
   let output2 = -2;
   let output3 = -3;
   output1 = Math.floor((Math.random()* sidesNumber + 1));
   output2 = Math.floor((Math.random()* sidesNumber + 1));
   output3 = Math.floor((Math.random()* sidesNumber + 1));
```

The `output` varaible is `-1`, `-2`, etc.

So to append the variables as `Math.floor((Math.random()* sidesNumber + 1))`, use `+=` instead of `=`.

I've also realized `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =` should be `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML +=`. I fixed that too.

```js
{
  let sidesNumber = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number of sides for your dice:", ""));

   let output1 = -1;
   let output2 = -2;
   let output3 = -3;

   while( output1 != output2 || output1 != output3 )
   {
       output1 += Math.floor((Math.random()* sidesNumber + 1));
       output2 += Math.floor((Math.random()* sidesNumber + 1));
       output3 += Math.floor((Math.random()* sidesNumber + 1));
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += output1 + " " + output2 + " " + output3;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're very almost there.

Currently, instead of displaying each roll on the screen, your script rolls the dice invisibly in the background and the roll is displayed only when the desired result occurs.

To display each roll, swap the line:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output1 + " " + output2 + " " + output3;
```

for something like:

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<p>' + output1 + " " + output2 + " " + output3 + '</p>';
```

---

**Working Example:**

```js
{
  let sidesNumber = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number of sides for your dice:", ""));

   let output1 = -1;
   let output2 = -2;
   let output3 = -3;

   while( output1 != output2 || output1 != output3 )
   {
       output1 = Math.floor((Math.random()* sidesNumber + 1));
       output2 = Math.floor((Math.random()* sidesNumber + 1));
       output3 = Math.floor((Math.random()* sidesNumber + 1));
       document.body.innerHTML += '<p>' + output1 + " " + output2 + " " + output3 + '</p>';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example storing the values inside a `ul` element

```js
{
  let sidesNumber = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number of sides for your dice:", ""));

   let output1 = -1;
   let output2 = -2;
   let output3 = -3;

   while( output1 != output2 || output1 != output3 )
   {
       output1 = Math.floor((Math.random()* sidesNumber + 1));
       output2 = Math.floor((Math.random()* sidesNumber + 1));
       output3 = Math.floor((Math.random()* sidesNumber + 1));
       
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<li>" + output1 + " " + output2 + " " + output3 + "</li>";
   }
   

}
```

```html
<ul id="result"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that every time you run your code you override the value of the innerHTML with `=`, you just have to fix it by writing `+=`

```
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += output1 + " " + output2 + " " + output3;
```